# How to retain customTitle in DialogFragment after screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I created a class that extends from DialogFragment. It worked fine, until I included a customTitle to this dialog. The problem I have until now, happened when changing orientation, leading the app to crash.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tdms.stingymoney/com.example.tdms.stingymoney.ListAccounts}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3828)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:158)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3566)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3437)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupTitle(AlertController.java:631)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:462)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
                                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:357)
                                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.onRestoreInstanceState(Dialog.java:423)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:396)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1970)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2042)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:165)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:543)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5336)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2234)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3828) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:158) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I solved the crash above setting null to customTitle in onDestroyView method, but now, when changing orientation, I lose my customTitle... This is my code now:

```
    public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

        View customTitle;

public interface OnYesNoResult{
            void onDialogResult(boolean result, int requestCode);
        }

        public AlertDialogFragment(){}

        public void setCustomTitleView(View view){
            this.customTitle = view;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstances){
            this.setRetainInstance(true);
            //
            Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

                            .setTitle("title")
                            .setCustomTitle(customTitle)
                            .setMessage("message")                         
                            .create();


            return dialog;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
           if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
                getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
            super.onDestroyView();
            customTitle = null;

           if (view != null) {
                ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                    parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**How can I keep my customTitle in DialogFragment, without crashing the app or losing it when changing the screen orientation?**

Thanks!

Comment: please remove onDestroyView call and when ever you want to dismiss dialog fragment use dismissAllowingStateLoss() and when ever you want to show dialog show it via fragment manager. And Also make sure you have handle onConfigurationChange call back properly. If you don't want to handle then add entry to manifest android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"

Comment: As I remember, when a screen changes orientation, it goes through onDestroy() and is then reCreated. Have you tried overriding the onCreate() then just simply setting the customTitle there?.

Comment: @sept The only question I have is: why should I remove the views from their parents in onDestroy method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
 if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();

            }
        }
    }
```

To

```
if(customTitle.getParent()!=null)
((ViewGroup)customTitle.getParent()).removeView(customTitle);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works! I didn't realize about the customTitle (View object) should be removed as well. I thought calling removeAllViews(), would solve the problems...